# Solve Determinant Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, determinant

Identify $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that (basically it is a determinant of a block matrix of size $n$):
$$
\left| \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{y}
& 
\mathbf{B} \\
\mathbf{c}
& 
\mathbf{D}
\end{array} \right| = 0
$$

where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times1}$, $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times1}$, $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-m)\times1}$ are column vectors, and $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times (n-1)}$, $\mathbf{D}\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-m)\times (n-1)}$ are matrices, and $m$ is an integer with $1 \le m \le n$, and $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is the unknown variable we want to solve.

I am not sure if the solution exists in general cases, but in my cases, solution $t$ exists.

I encountered such a problem when I want to write a computer program that finds a proper value $t$ that makes some points coplanar, such a geometric problem can be finally reduced to the above mathematical problem after some calculation.

The problem is quite challenging, because I would like to find a **closed-form solution** such that $t=...$ (right hand side is composed of known variables) so that computer can compute the solution $t$, otherwise we have to use symbolic calculation which is unfriendly to a computer. Even an **approximate approach** (e.g. iterative numerical approach) is also acceptable if the exact solution is too hard to find.

Do you have any thoughts on this? I would be grateful if you could provide some hints on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X:=\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}& \mathbf{B} \\
\mathbf{0}& \mathbf{D} \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $Y:=\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{y}& \mathbf{B} \\
\mathbf{c}& \mathbf{D} \\
\end{pmatrix}$. By multilinearity of the determinant it holds:
$$0=\det\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}+t \mathbf y& \mathbf{B} \\
\mathbf{c}& \mathbf{D} \\
\end{pmatrix}= \det X + t \det Y \Leftrightarrow t\det Y=-\det X
$$

So if $\det Y=\det X=0$, any $t\in \mathbb R$ works; if $\det Y=0\neq \det X$, no $t\in \mathbb R$ works; if $\det Y\neq 0$, then $t=-\frac{\det X}{ \det Y}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution looks very elegant!